# How and where we can modify react native expo bundleversion for IOS?

Tags: expo

Azure Devops release pipeline error :
original_server_error" =     {

```
    code = "ENTITY_ERROR.ATTRIBUTE.INVALID.DUPLICATE";
```

[altool]         detail = "The bundle version must be higher than the previously uploaded version.";

We don't know how to modify expo bundleversion and which file in react native expo, we are not using xcode to build project , we have only access of azure repository.We want to modify bunleversion manually to test release on app store testflight

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the `bundle version` for ios in the `app.json` / `app.js` file under the `ios` key,

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "ios": {
      "buildNumber": "1", <-- here
      "useHermes": false
    },
   }
}
```

here's the official expo documentation for the same
https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/app-versions/